# Dynamically resize a 3x3 grid of squares with the viewport

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, aspect-ratio

Thanks for taking the time to take a look at my dilemma.

What I am trying to do is fill a perfectly square div with a 3x3 grid of other square divs in HTML/CSS. I would like the container to be centered, take up the full height of the page (never scroll) and dynamically resize while retaining its aspect ratio when the view-port is resized. Each of the 9 cells that make up this larger square should resize dynamically as well as retaining their aspect ratios.

Here's as far as I got before getting really stuck by the fact that only the *WIDTH* is affected. When I resize my window, the height needs to change dynamically.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle-test.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="mainframe">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>Upper left</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>upper middle</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content content-lr">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>upper Right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-inside">
        <p>middle Left</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>middle</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content content-lr">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>middle Right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>Lower Left</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>Lower middle</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="content content-lr">
        <div class="content-inside">
          <p>Lower Right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html{
  background: url(home-assets/homebgtest.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  place-items: start;
}
.grid > * {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid > [style^='--aspect-ratio']::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the below working snippet as per your requirement of perfect square, hope it helps :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid>* {
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      Upper left
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      upper middle
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      upper Right
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      middle Left
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      middle
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      middle Right
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      Lower Left
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      Lower middle
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      Lower Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Girish, I really appreciate your help. However, the boxes in your version are changing aspect ratio. For my use case I really do need square boxes that resize and retain the aspect ratio. Thanks.

Comment: if you need them to be perfect square as per your requirement, then check this link https://codepen.io/girish/pen/NBZeKq,

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much. Do you want to repost your answer so I can choose it as the correct solution to my problem? I don't know if the UI will let me select a sub-comment.

Comment: It really did help me a lot! Unfortunately since I have less than 15 rep my upvotes are not shown but they are logged.